# Finding partial molar volume from an algebraic expression

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

> I'm given the equation $ V = 120X_1 + 70X_2+X_1X_2*(15X_1+8X_2)$ and told to calculate $\bar V_1 $ & $ \bar V_2$ and then to show that $ V = \Sigma_i X_i*\bar V_i$.

Since there are two mol fractions I substitute $ X_1 = 1-X_2 $ and solve for $ \bar V_i = \frac{ \partial \underline V}{\partial n_i} $

This gives:

$ V = 58X_1 -X_1^2 -7X_1^3+70 => \bar V_1 = 58-2X_1-21X_1^2$

and

$ V = -35X_2-22X_2^2+7X_2^3+120 => \bar V_2 = -35-44X_2-21X_3$

No matter how I use the partial molar volume expressions in the summation I always get a different V.

Even if I take the original volume expression and directly derive the partial volume expressions I can't seem to make anything equal out.

$ \underline V = 120n_1+70n_2+ \frac{n_1 n_2}{n}(15\frac {n_1}{n} + 8\frac{n_2}{n}) $

Which gives me

$ \bar V_1 = 120+\frac{n_2}{n}(15\frac{n_1}{n}+8\frac{n_2}{n}) + \frac{n_1n_2}{n}(\frac{15}{n})$

and

$ \bar V_2 = 70  + \frac{n_1}{n}(15\frac{n_1}{n}+8\frac{n_2}{n})$

So

$ \bar V_1 = 120+X_2(15X_1+8X_2)+15X_1X_2$

$ \bar V_2 = 70 + X_1(15X_1+8X_2) + 8X_1X_2$

applying the summation

$ X_1[120+X_2(15X_1+8X_2)+15X_1X_2]+X_2[70+X_1(15X_1+8X_2)+8X_1X_2] = V$

$ 120X_1 + 70X_2 +X_1X_2(45X_1+24X_2) = 120X_1 + 70X_2+X_1X_2(15X_1+8X_2)$

which then gives $ X_1 = -\frac{30}{16} X_2$ which obviously can't be true because mol fractions must be positive. I don't understand what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\underline{V}(n_1+n_2)V$.  So, differentiating by parts, $$\overline{V_1}=\frac{\partial \underline{V_1}}{\partial n_1}=V+(n_1+n_2)\frac{dV}{dX_1}\frac{\partial X_1}{\partial n_1}\tag{1}$$with$$\frac{\partial X_1}{\partial n_1}=\frac{n_2}{(n_1+n_2)^2}=\frac{X_2}{(n_1+n_2)}\tag{2}$$So, combining Eqns. 1 and 2, we have:  $$\overline{V_1}=V+\frac{dV}{dX_1}X_2\tag{3}$$Similarly, for $\overline{V_2}$, we have $$\overline{V_2}=\frac{\partial \underline{V_1}}{\partial n_2}=V+(n_1+n_2)\frac{dV}{dX_2}\frac{\partial X_2}{\partial n_2}=V-\frac{dV}{dX_1}X_1\tag{4}$$From Eqns. 3 and 4, it follows that $$X_1\overline{V_1}+X_2\overline{V_2}=V\tag{5}$$
It follows from Eqn. 3 that:
$$\overline{V_1}=128-2X_1+20X_1^2+14X^3$$

Comment: I see now that I was incorrectly using n as a constant, rather than $n_1+n_2$ This clarifies things, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing coefficient of 3 at the third term of the given relation for $V$. That is it should be $3*X$1$*X$2$*$($15X$1$+8$X2$)$. Then the relation V=$Σ$XV' becomes a valid equation. Hope it helps.